# correct way to manage memory of a big scrollview with multiple subviews

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am still very new to the objective c.

I have created an ipad app. it is a large horizontal scrollview with about 6 subviews in it.

Currently what i do is, i init all subviews at the very beginning once and for all.

When i use activity monitor to profile my app, it shows tat:

Real memory: 65-75MB
Virtual memory: 152.63MB

I am considering whether should I optimize my app to have a lower memory footprint. I know in my mind there are 3 ways of initing the subviews

- init all at the beginning, all
  views are alive and kept in memory
  until app closed. This doesnt look
  efficient but since there is no
  deallocation and reallocation,
  there's no chance that the memory
  will leak. (what i m doing now)
- init one view at a time, when u leave
  a view, do not destroy it so that
  when a view is revisited there is no
  need to reinit it again
- init one view at a time, when u leave a view,
  destroy it immediately. When it is to
  be revisted, we have to realloc
  again.

What is the common approach / best practise in doing this?

Comment: Please don't use textisms when posting here. It doesn't make anyone inclined to help you.

Comment: "u" is still not a word.

Answer (score 0):

To know the better way to handle memory issue you can refer this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code). Refer to the page control example, which explain the best way of reusing the same view multiple times.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < view2.view.frame.origin.x) {
perform some condition
}
}
```

Comment: hi anand, thanks for the link. it looks like it is using the strategy #2 i mentioned, i.e. init the view only when it is showed but doesnt destroy it when leaving that view. let's see if we have more opinions...

Comment: Ok fine.. try this delegate method 
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;  
check for the condition whether in which view it is.
Then release other views. 
It should work for you.

Comment: how anand, i m not discussing technically how to write the codes but generally in concept, how pple alloc/dealloc subviews. I want to make sure i m using an approach that pple generally are using :D